# Exclude Specific Categories?

Tags: categories

the code I'm currently using to display categories is `<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' ';}?>`

I would like to exclude a category called "home-featured" or the category with ID "65" how would I add this to the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php
$exclude = array( 'home-featured' );
foreach( get_the_category() as $category ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $category->cat_name, $exclude )
        echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
}
?>
```